# ASP.NET Label text align

Tags: c#, asp.net

How can I align every row to the right? This doesn't work:

```
Label1.Text = String.Format("{0, 15}", "aaaaaaaa").Replace(" ", "&nbsp;")
                 + "<br />"
                 + String.Format("{0, 15}", "bbb").Replace(" ", "&nbsp;");
```

Comment: Oh dear, this looks like the hack of all hacks.  Do yourself a favor and learn about HTML standards and CSS.  I would add a `CssClass` attribute to your `<asp:Label />` and do the styling with CSS.

Comment: oh my god...I don't want to start a revolution :D, I know how to do this with div-s and more labels...But that's not my question. Now I see -2 votes and 3 (bad) answers xD

Comment: @e-MEE How are the answers bad? they all achieve what you are aiming for.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

When you add your label in the .aspx page, declare it with a CSS class or with style="text-align: right;".

```
<asp:Label id="Label1" runat="server" width="100px" style="text-align: right;" />
```

If you want to change the alignment during run-time, your best bet is to change the CssClass property of the Label.

```
Label1.CssClass = "right_align";
```

In your CSS:

```
.right_align { text-align: right; }
```

Comment: yea...I tried this, but without the `width="100px"`. Now it's okay thanks :)

Answer (score 3):

I don't understand why you are trying to do your alignment from the code behind. Put the label in a control on the page which has a specific alignment set. If your creating the label in the code behind then create a control with the specific alignment that can have a label inserted into it programmatically.

Answer (score 1):

In C#, as pseudo code for asp.Net:

```
var label = new Label();
label.TextAlign = ContentAlignment.MiddleRight; // Aligns to right
label.RightToLeft = RightToLeft.Yes; // Changed direction to rtl (might reverse the meaning of TextAlignment
```

Or if you want to use string padding:

```
string pad, aaaa = "aaaa";
pad = aaaa.PadLeft(6); // "  aaaa"
pad = aaaa.PadLeft(6, '-'); // "--aaaa"
pad = aaaa.PadRight(10); // "aaaa      "
pad = aaaa.PadLeft(6).PadRight(8); // "  aaaa  "
pad = aaaa.PadLeft(6).PadRight(8, '.'); // "  aaaa.."
```

Comment: [I don't find any TextAlign or RighToLeft properties](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.label_properties.aspx)

Comment: Tym Pollack has the syntax for asp.Net in his answer.

Answer (score 1):

To align a label/textbox from code behind, you can use like this:

```
Label1.Text = "<center>Your Text to print here..</center>";
```

Answer (score 0):

Click on the label, go to properties, see there in an align attribute, set to Right1

Comment: Complex pages often are not able to be rendered in the view designer.

Answer (score 0):

Or you could just do it this way.

```
<asp:TableCell HorizontalAlign="Right">
    <asp:Label ID="lblGrossPay" runat="server" Text="2, 375"></asp:Label>
</asp:TableCell>
```